# Should I use the LIKE predicate or fetch all rows and process them on the client?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, java, like

I am optimizing my application, while this task, I find one query which is fetching data from database using `like` .
and database rows are around 10000.

So is this a good way to use `like` in query or I should fetch data from database and then process at server side language, like in `JAVA`

I need opinion, Please provide your valuable inputs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizing in SQL Server is (to large extent) about reducing resource usage. LIKE gives you the ability to seek in an index (if you don't have a wildcard in beginning), and also return less data from the operator (and in the end to the client). I very much doubt that any advantages can be achieved by doing such filtering in the client app instead. But, of course, there can be additional consideration to your example that you didn't disclose (not much info was given).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, they are realy helpful, and this help to resolve the performance! Thanks alot